# Elevate NodeJS/Electron process on Windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, electron

I'm currently building an app in Electron/NodeJS and am at a point where I'll need to elevate privileges on Windows to do a specific task (only Win7+ are a concern). How can I do this programmatically? I'll even take executing a bash script if it gets the job done.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to UAC elevate, use the `runas` module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/runas

Comment: Is there a newer approach to this problem? Unfortunately `runas` appears to be no longer maintained.

Answer (score 2):

I did some file writes using use node-powershell module :[node-powershell](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-powershell)

```
 const ps = new Shell({
    executionPolicy: 'Bypass',
    noProfile: true
});

ps.addCommand(`Start-Process -WindowStyle hidden cmd -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList '/c mkdir "C:\\Program Files\\foo"'`);
```